# "ImportError no module named" error when package with msg also has setup.py and installed

Tags: ros, catkin-make, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a package with a foo.msg and a python module my_package/src/my_package/bar.py that works fine in the devel space- I can import the msg or alternatively import the python module just fine.  But after running catkin_make install the I get an import error:

```
catkin_make install
source devel/setup.bash
python
>>>> from mypackage.msg import Foo
>>>>
>>>>  # (no error output, worked fine)
source install/setup.bash
>>>> from mypackage.msg import Foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Import Error: No module named my_package.msg
```

I commented out the `catkin_python_setup` from the CMakeLists.txt and rebuilt (`rm -rf build devel install` followed by `source /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash` seems safest which maybe ought to become the topic of another question...), then the import works fine.

One thing I notice is that the module bar.py is installed into install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/my_package, and there are no **init**.py files in that directory, only one directory lower in msg (it contains **init**.py and _Foo.py and pyc versions).

This is jade with Ubuntu 14.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260820/%22importerror-no-module-named%22-error-when-package-with-msg-also-has-setup.py-and-installed/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2017-05-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-05-01**:
Actually now that I try it the importing of `bar` isn't working in the devel space either, so that being configured wrong may be a component of the problem.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-05-01**:
my_package/src/my_package/ was missing **init**.py, added it and now this works:
from my_package.bar import bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer is to make sure that my_package/src/my_package/**init**.py exists, otherwise it can't import that module but also screws up msg modules from the same package when installed.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1